# how to get a text string from

Tags: java, string, webdriver, testng

I am creating an automatic test for some webs and I'm using WebDriver, TestNG and code that is written in Java. On the page is shown register of categories, in parentheses is number of auctions and i need to get this number as variable, but i don't know, how.

I use the following code:

```
WebElement number1_1_vse = (driver.findElement(By.linkText("Vše")));
String text_vse1_1 = number1_1_vse.getText();
```

but output is only: "Vše" without (number of auctions)

[link to the website](http://www.labmultis.info/jpecka.portal-exdrazby/index.php?c1=2&a=s&aa=&ta=1)

[screenshot -> image with the number](http://postimg.org/image/4vodvywrp/)

can anyone advise me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With linktext you are finding the nested a which text is `Vše` only. You need to find the li containing the text `Vše (949)`
Use the following css selector to identify the element

```
By bycss =By.cssSelector(".list.list-categories>li:first-child");
WebElement number1_1_vse = driver.findElement(bycss );
String text_vse1_1 = number1_1_vse.getText();
```

Comment: i have one question, how can I get next number? for example Byty (180)?

Comment: you can use "List<WebElement>" on whole "li" and then simple loop you can get all values

Comment: Can you give me a specific example? I dont know, how use "List<WebElement>"

Answer (score 2):

```
WebElement parent = number1_1_vse.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
// which will give you access to <li>
List<WebElement> childs = parent.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
// childs.get(1) has the result.
```

Comment: if I use this code, output from console is [[[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (7e6e0d0f-5cbb-4e48-992f-26d743a321a5)] -> css selector: .list.list-categories>li:first-child]] -> xpath: ..]] -> xpath: .//*], [[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (7e6e0d0f-5cbb-4e48-992f-.....

what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get the xpath value and then try to search it with below mentioned syntax :

findelementbyxpath("//*[@id="post-form"]/h2")

To get xpath value of and element : right click --> inspect element --> right click copy xpath